# Flight/booking code explanation

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, airlines

What do the letters mean in the following output from http://matrix.itasoftware.com/search.htm search results?

When I went to see a travel agent to book one of these flights, he mentioned the letter as shown in the screenshot below and implied that it was of some significance but failed to explain what it means or how it works.

[image]

Comment: enjoy South Africa!

Comment: @MarkMayo - Thanks Mark, but still have some planning left to do so you may see a few more questions from me yet.  Love this new Stackexchange group though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the fare class code.. See [this topic on `answers.yahoo.com`](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091021202051AAdrX4V) and [this page on the frequent fliers' website `cwsi.net`](http://cwsi.net/delta.htm) for full details.

> U = Economy/Coach Discounted

Answer (score 5):

The **U** is your fare class. It defines how changeable / non-changeable your ticket is, how upgradeable/not it is, how cancellable it is etc.

The best resource I've found for decoding the Delta fare classes is [cwsi](http://cwsi.net/delta.htm). They define the U class to be:

> Coach (discount web fare. domestic andinternational). Award mileage cannot be used to upgrade this class of service. Only Medallions receive domestic upgrades on this fare.

It looks to be one of the cheapest economy tickets they do, so probably don't count on being able to change / upgrade / cancel it....