# What does "M" signify in Emirates Economy flight

Tags: airlines, bookings, emirates

I have got my Economy class flight tickets in Emirates, and the booking class is "M". I have heard this signifies something.

Please could someone throw some light on this?

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing it with the Booking Class? An `M` as the booking class would signify something, while the letters/numbers in your 5-8 character booking reference are normally meaningless (but temporarily unique!)

Comment: I think that M refers to the booking class, is it? Google said so in some link.

Comment: Booking class != Booking Reference. Booking Class is a single letter, reference is 5-8 letters/numbers/letters+numbers (depending on airline)

Comment: Actually I just checked out the Emirates website, it's actually "M" class as printed in my ticket.

Comment: @CRMJunkie I edited the question accordingly, is it OK for you?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20252/are-there-subcategories-of-seats-even-within-economy-class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you'll want to take a look at [this question on subcategories of fares by booking class](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20252/are-there-subcategories-of-seats-even-within-economy-class), which will cover all the basics.

After that, all we need to look at is what kind of fare an `M` class on Emirates normally is. I can't seem to find a matrix of fare codes on the Emirates website, but as usual [FlyerTalk comes up trumps for this](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/emirates-skywards/1019552-list-booking-classes.html)

Assuming you've not got a very unusual ticket, then `M` will be `Economy - Discounted`

As long as you don't want to upgrade or change the ticket, that shouldn't really matter. However, it does mean you'll potentially have higher change fees, if changes are possible, and you're unlikely to be able to cancel. You'll probably also be further down the upgrade pile. I'm pretty sure that `M` counts as a Saver not a Flex fare, so you'll [only get 50% of the miles and tier status](http://www.emirates.com/au/english/help/faqs/FAQDetails.aspx?faqId=1103000) towards your Emirates Skywards account.

Answer (score 0):

There are different classes of air tickets. Going straight to the point, ECONOMY M belongs to a category booked in advance and for which refund is possible.